# use Pydantic to create CSV line

Tags: python, csv, serialization, decimal, pydantic

We use Pydantic to set the "Domain Models" and use them across the application layer.

```py
import datetime
from decimal import Decimal

from pydantic import BaseModel


class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    birth_date: datetime.date
    height: Decimal
    # other 100 fields, most of them Decimal
```

Now we need to export one of those models to a CSV, first implementation is easy:

```py
import csv
from typing import Iterable


def store(persons: Iterable[Person]):
    fieldnames = list(Person.schema()["properties"].keys())
    
    with open("/tmp/test.csv", "w") as fp:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(fp, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for person in persons:
            writer.writerow(person.dict())
```

But there is more, because we want all the decimals to be limited to two decimal places only, how can we achieve that?

Note: would not put serialization logic in the domain model, but I'm open to create a new model just for the serialization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a custom json encoder to round all Decimals in your model (Unfortuanatly it doesn't work to use `Decimal` as the result type in `json_encoders` as it's not JSON Serializable.

I've also defined a model `PersonOut` which inherits from `Person` so you don't have to store the serialization logic in the domain model. In the row writer the model is mapped to the serialization model.

```py
import csv
import json
from decimal import Decimal
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Iterable


class Person(BaseModel):
    """ Person domain model. """
    name: str
    height: Decimal


class PersonOut(Person):
    """ Person model used for serialization. """
    class Config:
        json_encoders = { Decimal: lambda v: float(round(v, 2)) }


def store(persons: Iterable[Person]):
    fieldnames = list(Person.schema()["properties"].keys())
    
    with open("test.csv", "w") as fp:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(fp, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for person in persons:
            writer.writerow(json.loads(PersonOut(**person.dict()).json()))

if __name__=="__main__":
    persons = [Person(name='test', height=1.743)]

    store(persons)
```